# Remove a node in a tree such that none of the remaining trees in the forest contain more than half of the nodes

Tags: tree, graph-theory

Let's think of a tree (acyclic connected graph), where we have N vertices and N-1 edges. How can we find if there exists a node such that removing it from the tree will make remaining trees in the forest having nodes of at most half of all the nodes. And if there exists such one, how can we know which one is it?

Comment: @dWinder there is no assumption that N is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be accomplish by traversing the graph starting from the leafs up and counting the sub-trees of each - if this completed without getting to `N/2` so you have found your node.

Consider the following pseudo-code.

```
set v.count = 0 for all nodes
nodes = all leafs in graph
while true:
    nextStep = new set
    for each v in nodes:
        if v.count < N/2:
            parent = v.parent
            parent.count += v.count + 1 // add another child 
            nextStep.push(parent) // notice that if he exist the new one override
    if nextStep empty:
        break  
    nodes = nextStep // updating with the new set
```

After done with this traverse on all node (DFS or what ever) - if you still had non-visited node (as v.count==0) then no such node exist to break the tree as requested. if all node visited then choose the one with the highest count and removing him will achieve your goal.

Hope that help!

Comment: Well, thanks but I found exactly what I want here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/centroid-decomposition-of-tree/

Basically, same steps as you described, thanks a lot!